# May one etch punctuation and trop into a sefer torah?

Tags: safrus

Is a Torah still kosher if various annotations are scored into the parchment? To be clear, I am asking not about writing annotations, but scratching them into the parchment.

Comment: Many yemenite communities actually did something like this. Many Poskim weren't excited by it (see Igrot Moshe YD 3:117, Yechavveh Daat 6:54)

Comment: סימן רעד - שצריך לכתב אותה לשמה, ודין תקון האותיות וזיונן ז סֵפֶר הַמְנֻקָּד, פָּסוּל. וַאֲפִלּוּ (ה) הֵסִירוּ מִמֶּנּוּ הַנִּקּוּד. וְכֵן סֵפֶר שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ (ו) פִּסוּק פְּסוּקִים, פָּסוּל. הגה: וְדַוְקָא שֶׁעָשָׂה הֶפְסֵק בִּדְיוֹ. אֲבָל אִם הִנִּיחַ אֲוִיר בֵּין הַפְּסוּקִים, כָּל שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ שִׁעוּר פָּרָשָׁה, כְּשֵׁרָה (תְּשׁוּבַת ריב''ש) .

Comment: Related, if not dup: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79857/501

Comment: @DannySchoemann Note (since you're probably interested) the "Rivash" reference there is a mistake by the printer (and confused many acharonim). The Rama is referencing the "Barukh SheAmar" and likely intended the practice as a Lekhatchila. Indeed most very old Ashkenazi scrolls have those gaps.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28352/11486

Comment: @DannySchoemann The question you linked is not really a dupe as that talks of writing in the margins of the Sefer Torah, not on the words themselves. The question I linked, I think, is more of a dupe.

Comment: @ezra yes, but one of the answers to that question specifically lists the prohibition of adding nikud and trop to a Sefer Torah, and sources it...  (BTW, I used yours in my close vote)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ta'amei Mikra and the Torah Scroll](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28352/taamei-mikra-and-the-torah-scroll)

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20141024051026/https://www.maharitz.com/hordot/sprim/sefer_t.PDF